# Blazor, in middleware check if the request path is going to produce a page

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, middleware

I'm writing a middleware in a Blazor application that basically checks if the system is sleeping and, if it is, presents a static HTML file.

```
public class PowerMiddleWare
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    private readonly PowerButtonWatcher powerButton;
    private readonly ILogger<PowerMiddleWare> logger;

    public PowerMiddleWare(
        RequestDelegate next,
        PowerButtonWatcher powerButton, 
        ILogger<PowerMiddleWare> logger)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.powerButton = powerButton;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {

        if (**LOGIC HERE** && powerButton.IsSleeping)
        {
            string filepath = "Pages/sleeping.html";
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;

            await context.Response.SendFileAsync(filepath);
        }
        else
        {
            await next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that all Websockets and API calls go through this middleware and, if the system is sleeping, their response is that HTML page, which I do not want. How can I filter only the pages? I know that if my pages all start with "/page/..." I can filter that way, but that's not a very elegant solution and I don't want to go that way due to the size of the application.

For example, is there any way to leverage the @page directive? In my head, I think it should have but for some reason, I'm not figuring it out.

Comment: Blazor-Webassembly does not use middleware or Websockets. Clarify your setup.

Comment: @HH Sorry, blazor server

Comment: If this is blazor server, then by definition, it's not sleeping, because it's running code on the server.

Comment: @Neil This sleeping is not the app it self, i.e. the app is still running but in "sleep" mode. The condition is "IsSleeping" but could be anything, like "IsMonday".

Comment: How about adding an attribute to each page that has an alternate static page, that is used if the middleware decides it's 'sleeping'?  You could then mark each page with a different static version if required.

Comment: @Neil sorry but that's not an acceptable solution in my case. There are a large number of pages and adding an attribute to every page is not a good ideia.

Comment: You've got 2 choices, either marking pages explicitly (as in my attribute idea) or by convention (your /page idea).  You seem to have rejected both.